# LED fade with LDR sensor depending on the light

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, sensors, c++, led

I need help on a project. I just started to experiment with arduino 2 weeks ago and I am building a lamp that react to movement and interactions.
So the idea is; when there is nobody in the room, the light stay white.
And when there is someone, it turns orange and I want it to « breathe » (fade function).

I am using a LDR sensor to make it happen and so far my code looks like:

```
int LDRvalue = 1;
int RedLED = 9;
int GreenLED=10;
int BlueLED=11;
int pinLDR = A0;

void setup()
{
pinMode(RedLED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(GreenLED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(BlueLED, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop()
{
LDRvalue = analogRead(pinLDR);
Serial.print("valeur ldr: ");
Serial.println(LDRvalue);

int colour = map(LDRvalue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
Serial.print("valeur mappe: ");
Serial.println(colour);


if(LDRvalue >= 1023)
{
analogWrite(RedLED, 255);
analogWrite(GreenLED, 255);
analogWrite(BlueLED, 255);
delay(1000);
}

else if((LDRvalue >= 800) & (LDRvalue < 1023))
{
analogWrite(RedLED, 255);
analogWrite(GreenLED, 255);
analogWrite(BlueLED, 255);
delay(1000);

}

else if((LDRvalue >= 600) & (LDRvalue < 800))
{
analogWrite(RedLED, 255);
analogWrite(GreenLED, 105);
analogWrite(BlueLED, 0);
delay(1000);

}
else if((LDRvalue >= 300) & (LDRvalue < 600))
{
analogWrite(RedLED, 255);
analogWrite(GreenLED, 35);
analogWrite(BlueLED, 0);
delay(1000);
}

else if((LDRvalue >= 150) & (LDRvalue < 300))
{
analogWrite(RedLED, 255);
analogWrite(GreenLED, 15);
analogWrite(BlueLED, 0);
delay(1000);

}

else if((LDRvalue >= 0) & (LDRvalue < 150))
{
analogWrite(RedLED, 255);
analogWrite(GreenLED, 0);
analogWrite(BlueLED, 0);
delay(1000);
}

delay(1);

}
void color(int red, int green, int blue)

{
analogWrite(RedLED, red);
analogWrite(GreenLED, green);
analogWrite(BlueLED, blue);
}
```

The code is working for the light changes depending on the human presence. 
But I don’t know how to make it fade and breathe when it turns orange.

Could you help me to make it happen ?

Comment: For one, you need to change the `&` in your if statements with `&&`. `&` is a bitwise AND, `&&` is a logical AND. Which one of the if statements is orange? It seems like you have 3 different kinds of orange.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have 3 orange because the more there is a light change the more it turns orange to red. I forgot to talk about it. But for each of these orange, I need it to breathe, maybe more each time.

Answer (score 1):

While some parts of your code don't make much sense to me, the breathing led code is easily searchable on the internet, with one of the first results being:

```
#include <math.h>
#define ledPin 11 
int i=0;
int breathe_delay = 15;   // delay between loops
unsigned long breathe_time = millis();
void setup() { }
void loop() {
  nonBlockingBreath();  // call the nonblocking function
  // yourOtherCodeHere();
}

void nonBlockingBreath() {
  if( (breathe_time + breathe_delay) < millis() ){
    breathe_time = millis();
    float val = (exp(sin(i/2000.0*PI*10)) - 0.36787944)*108.0; 
    // this is the math function recreating the effect
    analogWrite(ledPin, val);  // PWM
    i=i+1;
  }
}
```

As you can see the code above works for monochromatic LEDs only, so my advise is to combine the code above with a conversion from HSL to RGB, like [RGBConverter](https://github.com/ratkins/RGBConverter) library, specifically the `hsvToRgb` function.

This way your version of the `nonBlockingBreath` function will become:

```
byte[3] rgb;
void nonBlockingBreath() {
  if( (breathe_time + breathe_delay) < millis() ){
    breathe_time = millis();
    float value= (exp(sin(i/2000.0*PI*10)) - 0.36787944)*108.0; 
    hsvToRgb(hue, saturation, value, rgb);
    analogWrite(RedLED, rgb[0]);  // PWM
    analogWrite(GreenLED, rgb[1]);  // PWM
    analogWrite(BlueLED, rgb[2]);  // PWM
    i=i+1;
  }
}
```

Obviously you will have to set the `hue` and `saturation` variables accordingly to the tonality of orange you wish to *breath*.